# How to use chrome inspector to adjust height via css of ion2-calendar date picker component?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, datepicker, calendar, range

I am using the following date picker component for ionic 4 and I cannot figure out how to change the height of one of the elements as it shares the same name as the root element ion-toolbar.

https://github.com/hsuanxyz/ion2-calendar

I've tried the following code and it does change the ion-toolbar for the page, but not the one used within the element.

```
ion-toolbar { height: 50px !important; }
```

[image]

I don't know what css to use that will change the height, with all the extra stuff everywhere. Seems like I tried every scenario of elements, classes, componenets, etc and nothing changes the height of the section shown in the image.

The html calendar code is:

```
<ion-content>
      <ion-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateRange"
        (change)="onChange($event)"
        [options]="optionsRange"
        [type]="type"
        [format]="'YYYY-MM-DD'">
      </ion-calendar>
</ion-content>
```

And the typescript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarComponentOptions } from 'ion2-calendar';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datepicker-modal',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-modal.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datepicker-modal.page.scss'],
})
export class DatepickerModalPage implements OnInit {

  dateRange: { from: string; to: string; };
  type: 'string'; // 'string' | 'js-date' | 'moment' | 'time' | 'object'
  optionsRange: CalendarComponentOptions = {
    pickMode: 'range'
  };

  date: string;

  constructor() { }

  onChange($event) {
    console.log($event);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Nothing currently set via scss for this page.

Thank You